# Erro na instalação do Cordova + Ionic usando Node.js

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, ionic

Na tentativa de instalação do Cordova + Ionic usando o Node.js, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! unable to verify the first certificate
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\blablabla\npm-debug.log
```

Aparentemente a linha de maior relevância é esta abaixo:

> code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Qual seria a real causa do erro? Como pode ser resolvido?

Answer (score 0):

Tente limpar o cache e executar novamente os comandos:

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Comment: não funcionou assim.